# i have json data given below and i want to display it in a table

Tags: iphone, objective-c, json

```
Departments:[
  {
     "name":"Designing",
     "id":"1.1",
     Employees:[
     {
       "name":"Ramesh",
       "id":"1.1.1",
       "salary":"4lakhs"
     },
     {
       "name":"Suresh",
       "id":"1.1.2",
       "salary":"4lakhs"
     },
     {
       "name":"Mukesh",
       "id":"1.1.3",
       "salary":"4lakhs"
     }
     ]
     }
```

Comment: Are you already using SBJson framework?

Comment: What is your actual question about? You do not know how to display data in a table, or you cannot parse JSON?

Comment: well, in this case, there are 2 different questions - "How to parse JSON in Objective-C", and "How to fill data in an UITableView"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your .h file take  NSMutableArray :

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *employeeData;
```

in .m file

```
@synthesize employeeData;
```

Then Make Necessary changes in your code.

```
-(void)getEmpData
{

 self.employeeData=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];


     NSData *jsonData = @"Your Json Data";

            NSDictionary *jsonDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:kNilOptions error:&error];

        NSArray *arrDepartment = [jsonDictionary objectForKey:@"Departments"];

        NSArray *arrEmployees = [[arrDepartment objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"Employees"];


          self.employeeData= [arrEmployees mutableCopy];  
}



-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}

NSDictionary *dict =[self.employeeData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

             NSLog(@"empname=%@", [dict objectForKey:@"name"]); 
             NSLog(@"empid=%@",[dict objectForKey:@"id"]); 
             NSLog(@"salary=%@",[dict objectForKey:@"salary"]);
```

}

Comment: @Rajesh Let me know if its working for you so that it can be helpfull for others and you can accept the answer by clicking on the Check mark.

Comment: @prasad... now i am able to print only one of the three things(name,salary, id) what if i wanna print three data at a time....

Comment: @Rajesh If you want to print 3 data at a time in table view then you can create 3 UILabel Pragmatically with customized frame and add them as a sub-view  of cell.contentView. for more details click in the link:1.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4687238/uitableviewcell-content-view-adding-uilabels
2.http://www.iphonesdkarticles.com/2009/02/uitableview-adding-subviews-to-cells.html

Answer (score 2):

Do this:

```
 NSDictionary *jsonDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsondata options:kNilOptions error:&error];

NSArray *arrDepartment = [jsonDictionary objectForKey:@"Departments"];
```

Now u have arrDepartment which is tableview dataSource. So use accordingly

Further Get Employees like this:

```
NSArray *arrEmployees = [[arrDepartment objectAtIndex:0]  objectForKey:@"Employees"];
```

Comment: AFAIK that is the total code. Prince is just assuming that your JSON string is in jsondata and that jsondata is of type NSData*.

Comment: u have arrDepartment which is tableview dataSource

Answer (score 0):

Parse it using [SBJSON](http://stig.github.com/json-framework/) and Take this `Departments` array in NSMutableArray then access according to `indexpath.row;`

And your data should be in this format use http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ to check the json format

```
{
   "Departments":[
      {
         "name":"Designing",
         "id":"1.1",
         "Employees":[
            {
               "name":"Ramesh",
               "id":"1.1.1",
               "salary":"4lakhs"
            },
            {
               "name":"Suresh",
               "id":"1.1.2",
               "salary":"4lakhs"
            },
            {
               "name":"Mukesh",
               "id":"1.1.3",
               "salary":"4lakhs"
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```