# How to exract value one by one from Array in JSON Format in iPhone?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, json

```
Array 

DAATA (
            (
                    {
                Description = "<p>Image3</p>";
                "Image_Id" = 68;
                "Image_Path" = "aa6b74d47227ebd24561211a2c95199c.jpg";
                "Product_Address" = "Jaipur ,Rajastha";
                "Product_Booked" = N;
                "Product_Id" = 1;
                "Product_Info" = "The Indian Hotels Company Limited (IHCL) and its subsidiaries are collectively known as Taj Hotels Resorts and Palaces and is recognised as one of Asia's largest and finest hotel company. Incorporated by the founder of the Tata Group, Mr. Jamsetji N. Tata, the company opened its first property, The Taj Mahal Palace Hotel, Bombay in 1903. The Taj, a symbol of Indian hospitality, completed its centenary year in 2003. ";
                "Product_Latitude" = "26.9260\U00b0N";
                "Product_Longitute" = "75.8235\U00b0E";
                "Product_Name" = demo1;
                "Product_Offer_Price" = "$200";
                "Product_Price" = "$345";
                "Product_Type" = "five star";
            },
                    {
                Description = "<p>yo yo</p>";
                "Image_Id" = 75;
                "Image_Path" = "415e2e6b7a3b1850e06467ade2e10fa9.jpg";
                "Product_Address" = "jaipur,rajasthan";
                "Product_Booked" = N;
                "Product_Id" = 2;
                "Product_Info" = "five star";
                "Product_Latitude" = "";
                "Product_Longitute" = "";
                "Product_Name" = "hotel night rider";
                "Product_Offer_Price" = "$200";
                "Product_Price" = "$345";
                "Product_Type" = "five star";
            }
        )
    )
```

Comment: first write your code ...then i suggest to u .!!

Comment: check my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12580407/i-have-json-data-given-below-and-i-want-to-display-it-in-a-table/12580451#12580451

Comment: it seems your values have been already extracted, otherwise how could you even post them...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 NSString *responseString = [request1 responseString];//your json response will be here
 NSMutableDictinoary *dataDict = [[[responseString JSONValue] valueForKey:@"DAATA"]mutableCopy];//take response in dictinoary
 for(int i = 0 ; i<[[dataDict valueForKey:@"DAATA"] count];i++)
{
    if([[[[dataDict valueForKey:@"DAATA"] objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"Image_Id"] isEqualToString:@"court"])//get what you want here for example get "Image_Id"
    {
        NSMutableDictionary *dd=[[dataDict valueForKey:@"result"] objectAtIndex:i];
        [arrCourt addObject:dd];
    }
   and so on.........

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out [NSJSONSerialization](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and use it to parse your json string.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is to use [SBJson](http://stig.github.com/json-framework/) library.

```
- (void) connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *) conn 
{
//Call back called when data reception completes (stored in variable data)
NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSDictionary *results = [jsonString JSONValue]; // This is a new category added to the NSString by SBJSON
if ([results count]>0)
{ 
    // decoding a JSON object like so: {"result":"yes"}
    [results objectForKey:@"result"] ;
    if ([[results objectForKey:@"result"] isEqualToString:@"yes"])
    {
        [self registrationStateSetTo:YES];
        NSLog(@" registered OK "); 
    }
    else 
    {
        [self registrationStateSetTo:NO];
        NSLog(@" registration failed "); 
    }
}
}
```